# Extract GPS data from photo

Tags: ios, swift, ios8

I have a hard time because I want to extract the GPS coordinates from a photo. I use the function `imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` to pick an image and the I am inserting that image in a collectionView using the new Photos framework.
I want to extract the GPS coordinates from the photo. I have done some research and I am aware of the fact that UIImage does not contain all the metadata, so I tried using the `AssetsLibrary` framework. 
Inside `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` I am using the following code to extract the photo location:

```
    var referenceURL : NSURL = info.objectForKey(UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL) as NSURL
    var library : ALAssetsLibrary = ALAssetsLibrary()
    library.assetForURL(referenceURL, resultBlock: { (asset : ALAsset!) -> Void in
        var rep : ALAssetRepresentation = asset.defaultRepresentation()
        var metadata : NSDictionary = rep.metadata()


        let location: AnyObject! = asset.valueForProperty(ALAssetPropertyLocation)
        if location != nil {
            println(location)
        }
        else
        {
            println("Location not found")
        }


         })
    {
            (error : NSError!) -> Void in
    }
```

However, it doesn't find the location, even though I checked the image and it contains EXIF metadata (it contains also GPS locations, in which I am interested in). How can I retrieve the coordinates from photo?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found a solution using the following code:

```
 if picker.sourceType == UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary
    {
        if let currentLat = pickedLat as CLLocationDegrees?
        {
            self.latitude = pickedLat!
            self.longitude = pickedLong!
        }
        else
        {
        var library = ALAssetsLibrary()
        library.enumerateGroupsWithTypes(ALAssetsGroupAll, usingBlock: { (group, stop) -> Void in
                if (group != nil) {

                println("Group is not nil")
                println(group.valueForProperty(ALAssetsGroupPropertyName))
                group.enumerateAssetsUsingBlock { (asset, index, stop) in
                    if asset != nil
                    {
                    if let location: CLLocation = asset.valueForProperty(ALAssetPropertyLocation) as CLLocation!
                    { let lat = location.coordinate.latitude
                        let long = location.coordinate.longitude

                        self.latitude = lat
                        self.longitude = lat

                        println(lat)
                        println(long)
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else
                {
                println("The group is empty!")
                }
            })
            { (error) -> Void in
                println("problem loading albums: \(error)")
        }
    }
}
```

What it does is that it reads the entire album and prints the location if the photo has that property, else it prints "location not found". It does so for every photo in the album.So I have another question... I want to display the location info just for the photo that I have selected, not for the entire album.  Does anyone have a clue how this can be accomplished?

Answer (score 10):

`ALAssetsLibrary` is deprecated in iOS 10. Fortunately, with Photos framework, this is trivial to implement. When `imagePickerController(_ picker:, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo)` is called, you can retrieve location information through a simple lookup. Take a look at the code below:

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
   if let URL = info[UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL] as? URL {
       let opts = PHFetchOptions()
       opts.fetchLimit = 1
       let assets = PHAsset.fetchAssets(withALAssetURLs: [URL], options: opts)
       let asset = assets[0]
       // The location is "asset.location", as a CLLocation 

// ... Other stuff like dismiss omitted
}
```

Hope this helps. This is Swift 3, of course..

Comment: Have you tried this when using the camera? When I try to access `info[UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL] as? URL` it always comes back nil. I have location manager requirements fulfilled in my Info.plist file and prompt he user to access their location when in use. It still always comes back nil.

Comment: @MattLong yes I did, and it works fine. Look at https://gist.github.com/sumitlni/6421aece205ebefa647abe701d2429e0 for a gist - it's a ViewController you can embed in a sample app to see the code in action. This was tested successfully on the device.

Comment: @SubhojitMandal see https://gist.github.com/sumitlni/6421aece205ebefa647abe701d2429e0

Comment: @SubhojitMandal I think you misread my question. I am able to use this technique to grab the GPS details from photos that were captured using the Camera app that reside in the photo library, however, if you specify `imagePicker.sourceType = .camera` in your sample code, it doesn't work. That's what I was trying to get at when I said "Have you tried this when using the *camera*?" Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, used the wrong handle @SubhojitMandal. Meant to direct that comment to LNI.

Comment: @MattLong this is a known issue, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23103826/uiimagepickercontrollerreferenceurl-always-returns-nill for workaround. Though I'd say if you need to capture location from camera just query the current location.

Comment: @LNI Cool. That's what I ended up doing. I was just hoping you were onto something simpler that I was missing. Thanks. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 4):

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {

    if picker.sourceType == UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary {

        let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage
        pickedImage.image = image

        let url = info[UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL] as! NSURL
        let library = ALAssetsLibrary()          
        library.assetForURL(url, resultBlock: { (asset) in
            if let location = asset.valueForProperty(ALAssetPropertyLocation) as? CLLocation {

                self.latitude = location.coordinate.latitude
                self.longitude = location.coordinate.longitude
            }
            }, failureBlock: { (error: NSError!) in
                print("Error!")
        })
    }

    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

Finally managed to get this after trying a lot of different ways, it's remarkably poorly referenced in the apple documentation (or I just couldn't find it). Unfortunately any images that weren't taken through the stock "camera" app don't tend to have location metadata. But it works fine when they do.

Got the answer from https://stackoverflow.com/a/27556241/4337311

Comment: Hi Tim, just came across your question. The code you provided is similar to the one I have used, using picture url and then I wrote a result block like this: var resultBlock: ALAssetsLibraryAssetForURLResultBlock = {(myAsset: ALAsset!) -> Void in } Then after 'in' you would get the full metadata and access the properties you are interested in.

Comment: Hi Christian, I added the answer because you asked in your own answer to the question how to just acces the metadata of the individual image, and not the whole album. Glad you got there in the end anyway

Comment: this only works for the images which are there in PhotoLibrary. what about camera

Answer (score 3):

With **iOS 11** everything becomes **much easier** to recover GPS coordinate from a picture in your photo roll.

First import the Photo SDK

```
import Photos
```

Then before pushing the `UIImagePickerController`, ask the authorisation to access the data :

```
if PHPhotoLibrary.authorizationStatus() == .notDetermined {
    PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization { [weak self](_) in
        // Present the UIImagePickerController
        self?.present(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Then when you grab back the image from the `UIImagePickerController`, you only need to do the following to grab the coordinates :

```
let coordinate = (info[UIImagePickerControllerPHAsset] as? PHAsset)?.location?.coordinate
```

Answer (score 1):

iOS 12 & 13

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {

    // For Location
    if let asset = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.phAsset] as? PHAsset {
        print("============> \(asset.location?.coordinate.longitude ?? 0) \(asset.location?.coordinate.latitude ?? 0)")
    }
}
```